# Replacing an element from one list with all elements in another list

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble splicing one list into another at a given index.
The idea is as such:

"For each word in the primary list, if that word is X, replace it with all the words in the secondary list."

Here's an example. It inserts the secondary list into the primary list at the correct index:

```
primary_list = ['the', 'black', 'cat', 'jumped']
secondary_list = ['big', 'grey']

for i, word in enumerate(primary_list):
    if word == "black":
        primary_list[i] = secondary_list

primary_list 
>> ['the', ['big', 'grey'], 'cat', 'jumped']
```

The ideal output is:

```
['the', 'big', 'grey', 'cat', 'jumped']
```

I have also tried list comprehension:

```
primary_list[i] = [item for item in secondary_list]
```

Not only is it redundant, but it also just does the same as above.

There are some other answers here that used list slicing, but I wasn't sure how to use them in my syntax. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code was  because of two reasons in the following line:

1. trying to assign a list to a specific element in `primary_list`.
2. not using `secondary_list.copy()`.

If you had multiple occurrences of `'black'`, then this would `copy` the secondary list there. Any one of which if changed, it would later on change the others as they would share the same memory location.

```py
primary_list[i] = secondary_list
```

> Here is the solution.

```py
final_list = list()
for word in primary_list:
    if word=='black':
        final_list += secondary_list.copy()
    else:
        final_list.append(word)

final_list
```

**Output**:

```
['the', 'big', 'grey', 'cat', 'jumped']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using an intermediate `result` list:

```
>>> primary_list = ['the', 'black', 'cat', 'jumped']
>>> secondary_list = ['big', 'grey']
>>> result = []
>>> for word in primary_list:
...   if word == "black":
...     result += secondary_list
...   else:
...     result.append(word)
... 
>>> result
['the', 'big', 'grey', 'cat', 'jumped']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create another list and add primer list elements and secondary list elements.

```
primary_list = ['the', 'black', 'cat', 'jumped']
secondary_list = ['big', 'grey']
result_list=[]
for i, word in enumerate(primary_list):
    if word == "black":
        for secod_val in secondary_list:
            result_list.append(second_val)
    else:
        result_list.append(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach using slicing.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a[3:3] = b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
primary_list = ['the', 'black', 'cat', 'jumped']
secondary_list = ['big', 'grey']

for i, word in enumerate(primary_list):
    if word == "black":
        primary_list[i:len(secondary_list)] = secondary_list

print(primary_list)
```

```
['the', 'big', 'grey', 'cat', 'jumped']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using strings:

```
primary_list = ['the', 'black', 'cat', 'jumped']
secondary_list = ['big', 'grey']
for i in range(len(primary_list)):
    if primary_list[i] == 'black':
        primary_list[i] = secondary_list

final_list = repr(primary_list).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').split(', ')
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
['the', 'big', 'grey', 'cat', 'jumped']
```